# Trigger to prevent Insert Delete and Update of records based on date matching?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

In theory, I am trying to prevent some records from being edited- it should compare the system date and a row called `DateAdded` that stores dates as Date (YYYY-MM-DD).

If the the record is old (ie) Sysdate > DateAdded, prevent making changes to the record.

Comment: Seems easy enough to do with instead of triggers. You can even do the entire thing with a single trigger, though I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Do be careful if using triggers for this. It can generate false bug reports if you don't provide feedback that the values being updated are invalid. The application will just "update" but not actually do anything which is incredibly confusing to an end user.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T1
ON YOURTABLE
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
  if exists ( select * from inserted where DateAdded >= getdate() )
     begin
       update yourtable
       set DateAdded  = (select DateAdded from inserted)
       ...
       where yourtable.key = (select key from inserted);
     end
GO
```